# How to add regex to track url parameters in destination goals in google analytics?

Tags: regex, google-analytics, goal-tracking

I want to set up destination goals in google analytics for our donate page. We have 3 steps here..

- user lands on `/donate` then clicks the donation button
- which takes them to `rp-thanku/?donation_process_started=yes` and
- clicking on another button it finally takes to `/rp-thanku/?donated=yes`.
  I also wanted funnel visualization for this process to know how many people are making till the last step.

I have set up the goal as following but not sure if its right. I wanted to know if this is the right way to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As long as the final page is the only page containing "donated=yes" then you should be fine.